# Spring auto-wire dependency which has constructor argument

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, autowired

I have my mailing service with has constructor argument and implements an interface

```
public class MailServiceImpl implements MailService {
    private MailBo mail;

    public MailBO getMail() {
        return Mail;
    }

    public void setMail(MailBO Mail) {
        this.Mail = Mail;
    }

    public MailServiceImpl(MailBo mail) {
        throw exception if from and to address is not here
        this.mail = mail;
    }

    public void sendMail(){
        use mail object to send mail here
    }
}
```

so now i am trying to write a test which i want to create Mailserviceimpl instance autowired  with constructor argument passed in it.

i followed [this](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/05/08/spring-beans-autowiring-concepts/) link to autowire object with constructor, but i am getting below exception

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.model.MailBO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
```

my test class

```
public class MailServiceImplTest {


    @Autowired
    private MailService mailServiceImpl;

    @Test
    public void testSendValidMail(){
    //test
    }
}
```

EDIT:-

adding spring context

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.service" />



</beans>
```

EDIT 2:- 
i want my mailbo loaded with some values and inject as constructor object to mailserviceimpl

Comment: could you add your spring configuration?

Comment: Ok, as you are using component scanning you also need to provide the code (with package name & annotations) for MailServiceImpl & MailBO.

Comment: Is MailBo a spring-service or a POJO (model object)?

Comment: MailBo is model objecct

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `MailServiceImpl` and `MailBO` are Spring Beans. Then just annotate MailServiceImpl constructor by `@Autowired` and Spring will automatically injects constructor dependency